# Where can I find a list of all my deleted questions?

Tags: support, post-ban

I have been banned from asking question because of, among other things, too many deleted questions. [This page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans) states that "*the only way to end a posting block is to positively contribute to the site; automatic bans never expire or "time out". Begin by fixing your existing posts*".

But [this other page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted?lq=1) states "as of 23/Apr/2013: You can now view your own deleted questions ***if you already have a link to them*** (...) You have to have thought to bookmark your question, or you have to go digging for it in your browser history."

How can I improve my deleted questions if I can't find them?

**UPDATE:** And how can I improve a deleted question if I can't edit it?
[image]

Comment: You can't. The reason (which I not everyone agrees with) is that it will cause "enormous amounts of whining" from people who had their questions deleted.

Comment: Editing your deleted questions won't matter as no one else can see them or upvote them. You just have to keep going. Undelete by community is possible, but incredibly rare. I'm not sure if undeleting them yourself will help.

Comment: His point is that he can't keep going, as he has been post banned until he fixes his stuff

Comment: @StephenTG Only "question" banned. I guess SO wants him to post answers to undo the ban, which makes only a little sense to me.

Comment: @WesleyMurch That's not so. 10k+ users and mods can see them. More to the point, the whole reason for always allowing users to see their own deleted questions was to enable editing, so that they can flag for undeletion and escape question bans.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName 10k users can see them but again, only if they have the link. They do not appear otherwise.

Comment: You can see your recently deleted questions by clicking the "Questions" tab in your profile and following the "deleted recent questions" link at the bottom. Links to older questions are not display in your account are available only

Comment: You only had two deleted questions with one downvote between them. One was a self-delete, so I undeleted it for you.  The other was a borderline off-topic question that would have been better asked on Server Fault, but it's since it's too late to migrate it now (and because it was closed instead of migrated), I undeleted it as well.  Any other downvoted questions might still be contributing to the question ban. Please be sure to try and improve them.

Comment: @BilltheLizard Thanks. I'll take a note of the links, delete them, think of improvements and them undelete and apply such improvements. Is there any time limit on self-undeletions?

Comment: No, I don't think so. You should be able to take all the time you need.